# What is transformations in LLVM? How is is it related to passes in LLVM?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm just starting to learn about llvm and a bit confused with transformations and Passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An LLVM pass is something that goes through either by you or by an LLVM backend generated ***LLVM IR***. From the structure of said IR, we can do two things.

- Analysis in which we from the IR provides some sort of information about the program for static analysis. [The clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/scan-build.html) is an example of such a tool.
- Transformation: 
  Another option is that we change the IR as we pass through it. We make a transformation. Usually, we do this to make the resulting executable better. We optimize the code. This last part is what is called a transformation, or **Transform Passes** to quote the LLVM documentation. Simply stated, transformations are operations conducted by some transform pass, and that relates to changing the IR into some other form when executing the pass.

More information about this can be found here [LLVM passes](https://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html).